# iPad 2 hd, will i have memory issues?

Tags: ios, ipad, memory

I have an app that works on iPad 1st gen. This is a game, made using cocos2d framework.

The first iPad does have 256mb ram and using instruments(the memory monitor tool) i was able to determine that the app works at around ~90-110mb ram on the device (well lets just trust "Physical Memory Used" chart though the "Physical Memory Free" at the very beginning shows it is ~128mb free and then gets to ~3-4mb free after playing several levels and never gets higher)

So while it does have enough memory it caches the assets and when it runs out of ram the cached assets get released.

What i did is added the high res graphics to it. Almost all of the assets are loaded as 4bit assets so say if i have an asset 100x100 pix it will consume 100x100x4 = 40000 bytes ram; the same hd image will be 200x200 pix and will consume 200x200x4 = 16000 bytes ram; which is 4 times bigger!

So the question is - will it work fine on iPad 2 hd screen which has 512mb ram?

See if i multiply ~110mb*4 it will be ~440mb, what means it will be 512 - ~440 = ~72mb left for system. So i do not know if that is enough for system and it won't close the app. I am not sure but i think the 1st gen iPad may give around ~120-130mb ram for the app and then will close it. So that makes me think this won't work on the iPad2. Am i likely correct?

ps: i've tested the app on the 3d gen iPad which has 1gb ram and it runs just fine

Comment: The iPad 2 does not have an retina screen, so the physical resolution of the iPad 2 is the same as on the iPad 1. Only do the retina style images on a device that supports it, this way you keep memory low on device that can't handle the retina resolution.

Comment: wow thanks, my bad, i thought it's retina. well it seems the game won't have memory issues on any other devices then, correct me if am wrong, thanks

Comment: Does not seen to be so no.

Comment: iPhone3g has 128 ram and i had a lot mem issues adding hd graphics to it because it wasn't enough 256mb ram on the iPod touch 4 gen with 256mb ram so i thought i'll have the same issue here

Comment: if you post that as an answer i'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPad 2 does not have a retina screen, so the physical resolution of the iPad 2 is the same as on the iPad 1. Only do the retina style images on a device that supports it, this way you keep memory low on device that can't handle the retina resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad 2 has the same screen resolution as the original iPad, so it will not use the new retina artwork that you are adding to the app. This means it should run fine on the iPad 2 if its already running original iPad.